# How to remove automatic space after greek lettters using the cairo library?

Tags: r, expression, legend, paste, cairo

I am using expression() to create a string that includes greek letters. My legend label is as follows:

```
legend.label = paste(mu, "+", sigma, ", ", mu, ", ", mu, "+", sigma, " of
random strategy", sep ="")
```

This should give me something like: μ+σ, μ, μ+σ of random strategy, but instead I am getting this:
[image]

It seems as if there is an automatic space after the greek letters. I already tried using the * and ~ operator, but it didnt help. I am using the cairo package to create anti-anialised plots. However, without using the cairo package I seem to get the right result. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% percent sure what you want to know. But mu in this case is the expected value and sigma is the standard deviation from that expected value. mu + sigma builds the upper bound of a confidence interval and mu - sigma the lower bound.

Comment: Oh sorry, think i got what you mean. mu and sigma are just the greek letters they are no variables. R recognises them if you call them like that. I did not define them beforehand.

Comment: I didnt define them and didnt load any package. I noticed that I also get the error, interestingly I still got the result pictured above. Anyways, your solution solves the problem with out using them. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: strange ! you're welcome, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you defined the "greek letters" but you can use the unicode to put them without space in your legend:

```
plot(0:1, 0:1, type="none", main="\U03BC+\U03C3, \U03BC, \U03BC+\U03C3 of
random strategy")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is described in `help("plotmath")`:

```
plot(1)
legend("top", legend = expression(paste(mu + sigma, 
                                        ", ", 
                                        mu,
                                        ", ",
                                        mu + sigma,
                                        " of random strategy")),
       lty = 1, col = "red", bty = "n")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: @CathG The spaces are not around the letters, but around the `+` signs (as they should). You could avoid them with `expression(paste(mu, "+", sigma))`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried many things before and this is one of them. It works totally fine as long as you do not use the cairo library to create the plot. Unfortunately, I had to use this library, which resulted in the same spaces as pictured in my post above. The solution from CathG however doesnt have that problem.